# Webpack won't recompile files using docker

Tags: webpack, docker-compose, react-redux

I have a reactjs and redux, project that uses webpack and it's built using a Dockerfile. It is a boiler-plate with some previous configuration, you can get the files by clonning this repo: https://github.com/CheesecakeLabs/react-redux-boilerplate.

So in order to run the react server I did create a docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '2'

services:
  frontend:
    image: redux
    container_name: redux
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - PORT=5000
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
```

The server starts normally using the dev option, however when I do any change to the index.js file under the  the project won't update and make the changes, even with those dependecies under package.json:

```
"webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.6.1",
"webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.0.0",
"webpack-manifest-plugin": "^1.1.0"
```

My OS is Linux: SUSE 42.1.

Thank you for your time!

**EDIT 1:**

Made some changes to the Dockerfile in order to run the server using the development option:

```
FROM node:6

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
COPY yarn.lock /usr/src/app/
RUN yarn

COPY . /usr/src/app

RUN yarn build
EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["yarn", "dev"]
```

**EDIT 2:**
Modified my Dockerfile to this and docker-compose file is still the same. 
But when I run docker-compose up, it fires this error:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:6

RUN npm install -g webpack
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app
COPY yarn.lock /usr/src/app
RUN yarn

EXPOSE 5000

CMD bash -c "yarn build && exec yarn dev"
```

Error:

```
error Couldn't find a package.json file in "/usr/src/app"
```

What exactly this does?

```
COPY package.json /usr/src/app
COPY yarn.lock /usr/src/app
```

**EDIT 3:**
ls -alh output:

```
drwxr-xr-x 5 giovanni users 4,0K Ago  1 14:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 giovanni users   88 Ago  1 14:20 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 giovanni users  392 Ago  1 14:19 .babelrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 giovanni users 1,1K Ago  1 14:19 circle.yml
-rw-r--r-- 1 giovanni users  211 Ago  1 15:05 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 giovanni users   18 Ago  1 14:19 .dockerignore
-rw-r--r-- 1 giovanni users  294 Ago  1 14:19 .editorconfig
-rw-r--r-- 1 giovanni users   16 Ago  1 14:19 .eslintignore
-rw-r--r-- 1 giovanni users   34 Ago  1 14:19 .eslintrc.json
drwxr-xr-x 8 giovanni users  163 Ago  1 14:19 .git
-rw-r--r-- 1 giovanni users   12 Ago  1 14:19 .gitattributes
-rw-r--r-- 1 giovanni users   82 Ago  1 14:19 .gitignore
-rw-r--r-- 1 giovanni users 3,8K Ago  1 14:19 package.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 giovanni users  512 Ago  1 14:19 postcss.config.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 giovanni users  384 Ago  1 14:19 README.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 giovanni users  997 Ago  1 14:19 server.js
drwxr-xr-x 9 giovanni users  199 Ago  1 14:19 src
-rw-r--r-- 1 giovanni users   66 Ago  1 14:19 stylelint.config.js
drwxr-xr-x 2 giovanni users   28 Ago  1 14:19 tests
-rw-r--r-- 1 giovanni users 1,7K Ago  1 14:19 webpack.config.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 giovanni users 2,2K Ago  1 14:19 webpack.config.production.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 giovanni users 1,5K Ago  1 14:19 webpack.config.server.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 giovanni users 1,4K Ago  1 14:19 webpack.config.vendor.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 giovanni users 220K Ago  1 14:19 yarn.lock
```

**EDIT 4 (Final):**

Make sure your docker-compose.yml file is in the right folder...problem solved!

The solution was to link the source code on the host to the container using volumes on the docker-compose.yml file:

```
volumes:
 - .:/usr/src/app
```

So my docker-compose file looks like this:

```
version: '2'

services:
  frontend:
    image: redux
    container_name: redux
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - PORT=5000
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
```

And the Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:6

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN npm install -g webpack
EXPOSE 5000

CMD bash -c "yarn && exec yarn dev"
```

Comment: Are you rebuilding the Dockerfile when updating `index.js`

Comment: Do i have to rebuild it everytime? If I rebuild it, it makes the changes, but I tought there was a easier way to do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to use is volumes in your case. I believe you are doing the development on the host and trying to test it

```
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
COPY yarn.lock /usr/src/app/
RUN yarn

COPY . /usr/src/app
```

The above `COPY` commands are copying the code at that instance and putting that in a docker image. Any changes that you make in your host system to the files will not impact the image or the running containers based on those images. Consider it as more of a snapshot. So for your development change the docker file as below

```
FROM node:6

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
EXPOSE 5000

CMD bash -c "yarn build && exec yarn dev"
```

Change the `docker-compose` file as

```
version: '2'

services:
  frontend:
    image: redux
    container_name: redux
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - PORT=5000
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
```

The volume will map your current folder inside the docker to `/usr/src/app` and any change you make would be instantly available inside the container.

I assume `yarn dev` does any hot reload required for the code changes.

Comment: Okay, so i did your change but this, but compose says webpack not found: redux | sh: 1: webpack: not found

Comment: I modified your Dockefile assuming all is there. Whatever is missing you should add `RUN npm install -g webpack` and any other dependencies to your `Dockerfile`

Comment: Ok, after i installed webpack it says: Error: Cannot find module 'webpack'
redux |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)

Comment: I am not sure how your redux or yarn setup works. But all of these means you are missing some basic installation/configuration steps. Which could be a `npm install` on the source directory or probably the `yarn` command which I ignored in my answer. So check and fix these issues one by one

Comment: Your are copying package.json from your current directory. If it is not found then you need to see what the issue is. Post the output for `ls -alh` command

Comment: As far as I understand what webpack does is: get's package.json and yarn.lock files, run yarn and yarn build and it will install all the dependencies for the project, listed on package.json of course. The server config for development is on webpack.config.js I believe...